# Tkinter install not working after pip install tk

Tags: python, tkinter

I need Tkinter to use in one of my projects as a button etc.
i pip installed Tkinter with the code below as i followed a tutorial online and it said to

```
 pip install tk
```

is this not correct as when I import Tkinter `import Tkinter`. it says module not found?

I have tried to restart my project and have tried every possible pip install combination ever.

Please help explain Tia.

Comment: in python3 it is `tkinter` also it is built in so no need to install, also don't follow python2 tutorials if You have python3 also python2 is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore (unless maintenance or sth)

Comment: @matiiss that fixed it until it now says it cant call the module?? i have code that is `import tkinter as tk` then it runs to `tkWindow = tk()

button = Button(tkWindow, command=va)`

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: File "C:\Users\marsh\Downloads\shop sales.py", line 71, in <module>
    tkWindow = tk()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable  @ Matiiss

Comment: it's `Tk()` as I said don't follow python2 tutorials if using python3, also python is case-sensitive also also use `snake_case` for variable and function names (per PEP 8)

Comment: It's `tk.Tk()` @Matiiss, he didn't import it directly, he just imported tkinter

Comment: @Maiiss do you have an email so can run the code for a check as it still doesnt work??

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński How do install it properly then

Comment: You don't install it, it's built-in, instead of `tkWindow = tk()` do `tkWindow = tk.Tk()`

Comment: If you do from tkinter import *, you will be able to just do tkWindow = Tk() - refer to my answer below.

Comment: I suggest You take a look at this tutorial about tkinter: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA) and more resources [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, Tkinter is built in. But you have to use a lowercase letter. Don't use "Tkinter", use "tkinter" instead.

Also, don't use "import tkinter", use "from tkinter import *", to import everything.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
def command():
  print("Hello, world!")
root = Tk()
root.title("tkWindow")
btn = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=command)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, remember that when you import everything from Tkinter (using from tkinter import *), you don't use tk.Tk() or tk.Button(), you just have to use Tk() and Button().

This should work for you. Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I have heard that it is not generally a good practice to import `*` everything from a module unless You are sure about it, just import what You need, like `from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button`

Comment: im just trying to run a page with a button to run a voice assistant when pressed could someone help and leave the function area out ??

Comment: no, i'll edit the code and show you how to do that. refresh your page after a minute, i'm adding the button function now!

Comment: @MarshallPodcasts did You watch the tutorial or not? have You found any python3 tkinter tutorials ([here is one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA))

Comment: copy and paste this code now, it'll give you a button, and when you click it, it should print Hello, world!

Comment: also the latest edit: usually (per PEP 8) imports are at the top of the file, then comes the rest (like function in this case "should" be defined after importing from tkinter)

Comment: however code does still work if you import modules after as well.

Comment: True but it is not that You "must" but rather "should" put imports at the top of the file especially because in the definition You may accidentally include something that is not yet imported.

Comment: True, so basically it makes your code more organized, and easier to understand i guess.

Comment: @MarshallPodcasts, does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it depended on what version of python I was using. When I was trying to do turtle graphics for the first time, my Tkinter module wasn't importing. After `from tkinter import Tk`, it worked. When we moved to python 3.8.5, it clearly had tkinter built into python 3 already, so try pip installing (just in case), then try `from tkinter import Tk` again. If it isnt working, check to make sure that you're on the latest version of python!

Comment: This should be changed to "from tkinter import Tk", "from tkinter import tk" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I edited that now. :)